# How to add DRM protection to my DRM-free ebooks?

Tags: pdf, ebooks, drm, epub, mobi

I have started reading ebooks, and found store selling DRM-free ebooks, which are watermarked with my real name and email address. I copy these ebooks to my PocketBook Basic Lux 2.

In case, that I loose my reader, I don't want finder to be able to steal books. For following reasons:

- I don't support illegal way of acquiring work,
- I wouldn't like to have my name wandering around the world as part of stolen ebooks.

However, I want to keep my ebooks stored at home in DRM-free way. Just, have them protected in my ebook reader in case of stealing/loosing.

Is there a (preferably CLI) way to add DRM protection to my ebooks?

Formats: epub, pdf, mobi.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of your ebook reader if the offer a means of encrypting the storage with a password.

Comment: It's unlikely you really want this as you would also need to operate a DRM server for devices to authenticate with, and possibly even develop your own software reader that integrates with your scheme. It's probably simpler to try to remove the watermark instead. Also try contacting the publisher and explaining your concerns, and ask them what you should do if your device is ever stolen.